# Accumulation points of a sequence in a metric space

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I am working with sequences in metric spaces and I think the following may happen.

Let $(X,d)$ a complete and separable metric space, if $x \in X'$, we know that exist a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_n \to x$, I want to prove that $x_n \in X'$ for infinite elements of the sequence.

I tried to prove by reduction to the absurd assuming that there are infinite isolated points but I do not arrive at anything. Can you help me to demonstrate or refute this idea.

Comment: Any assumption on $X’$?

Comment: $X$ is complete and separable. I'll edit it.

Comment: Ok, but I meant $X’.$ It is a subset of $X$ right? Do you have any assumption on it? Otherwise we may just take $X’=\{x\}.$

Comment: I have not assumption of $X'$.

Comment: @TresTresUno: By $X'$ you mean the derived set of $X$, i.e., the set of non-isolated points of $X$?

Comment: Yes, $X'$ is the derived set of $X$.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’re trying to prove is false. Let $X=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ with the usual Euclidean metric; this a complete, separable metric space, $X'=\{0\}$, and the sequence $\left\langle\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$ converges to $0$ but is contained entirely in $X\setminus X'$.

Comment: Of course, thank you very much.

Comment: @TresTresUno: You’re very welcome.